# Azure DevOps: Field with default value containing another fields value

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to find a way in Azure DevOps of displaying a field on a User Story layout that is made up of a URL plus the value of another field on the same story.

We have an external support ticket system where all of our support calls are logged. When the story (or even Defect) is created, we have a field where a support reference is entered.

I want another field that combines a URL and the support reference so it creates a link to the support ticket.

Is this do-able?

Thanks,

Craig

Answer (score 0):

This is achievable. You can Add a custom field to a work item type for an inherited process.

> 1,First you need to create a inherited process.

Go to **Organization settings**, From the **Process** page under **Boards**, open the **…** context menu of the process you'll use to create an inherited process, and then choose Create inherited process. Choose the same system process—Agile, Basic, Scrum, or CMMI—that was used to create the project that you want to customize.

[image]

> 2, Add a custom field to an existing work item type for the inherited process.

From the Process page of the selected inherited process, choose the work item type(User Story) you want to add the custom field to.

Select the work item type and click **new field** or **...** to add a field under a group.

[image]

For example i add a new field **Support Url** under group **Planning**(click Options to define a default value for this field).

[image]

> 3, Apply the customized process to your project.

Click **team projects** of the process shown as below screenshot.

[image]

Open the … context menu for the process and choose the Change team projects… option.

[image]

Then you will have the custom field with default value for the work item type in your project.

For detailed steps please check Microsoft Document [there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/add-custom-field?view=azure-devops).

> Update:
>   Field value made up of a static part, plus another field

There is no direct way or any tool i can find to achieve this. However there is a complicate workaround to achieve this.

You can try creating a service server to to combine the field values and update the workitem field with [workitem update rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#update-a-field), and add a service hook to this service server.

You can refer to the service hook sever provided by Microsoft. Check [reate a pull request status server with Node.js](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/create-pr-status-server?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, not quite what I'm after. I've already created multiple custom fields, I needed a field that provided a URL to the viewer, which was made up of a static part, plus another field.

Comment: You can try creating a service server to to combine the field values and update the workitem field, and add a service hook to this service server. Check above update.

Comment: Service hook to PATCH an API call to itself to update the value.  I'll try to type up a complete answer soon as I'm working on a separate yet related customization.

Answer (score 0):

I found this extension called **URL Field** that does exactly that and I just tried it and it works. For more info, check its page on the [marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=krypu.url-field).

It supports these scenarios:

1. A fixed static URL that is always the same for every workitem.
2. A dynamic URL that combines a static base URL with some parametres
   taken from an other field.
3. A manual URL that is fully based on an other field.

This is how it looks while configuring it:
[image: Configuring the extension]

This will add the work item title as a query param to the google link.